# How do I perform Bessel function computations for data imported from MS excel?

Tags: export, import, special-functions, data-acquisition

I am trying to perform Bessel function computations of the form Jn(b*x) where n is the order of the Bessel function. I have three columns representing x, b and n. I wish to import this data into Mathematica and compute Jn(bx) and export the results back to either .csv or .dat formats where Jn(bx) will now be my 4th column. I got a very nice tutorial [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1165759) but it is not particularly suited for what I am looking for. Your kind suggestions would be highly appreciated.
My data is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fp32fr3nvkih7r/bessel.xlsx?dl=0)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = Import["bessel.xlsx"] // Transpose // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
  Delete[#, 1] &
```

This imports, the file, flattens it to a matrix and deletes the header row. You may need the complete path name if the data is not in the current directory. Then

```
Table[BesselJ[m[[i, 2]], m[[i, 1]] m[[i, 3]]], {i, Length[m]}]

{0.0349786, 0.0217276, 0.0136127, 0.0676302, 0.0527186, 0.0394126, 0.03222, 0.0256004, 0.0240566, 0.247746}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the header also with an import option. And instead of `Table`, you can also apply a functional approach with `Apply` (used as `@@@` here):

```
data = Import["bessel.xlsx", "HeaderLines" -> 1][[1]];
f = {x, n, b} \[Function] BesselJ[n, b x];
f @@@ data
```